# Facebook Graph API sharing after publish_actions permission is removed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an Web App from which users can share content to their Facebook profiles or pages.

Facebook has said in their [breaking changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24) that they will remove publish_actions permission from August 1st and alternatively if we want to let the users of our app share to Facebook we need to use their [sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing).

The problem is I want my users to be able to share to multiple Social Media's, that they have saved in our app with long living token, through a single click. This doesn't seem possible with the method mention by them using their [sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing).

I would like to know If there is some method for doing this using saved long living token's or If there is any way by which I can retain my publish_actions permission, for example like partnering with Facebook

Comment: No, there is currently no way to do that. Whether Facebook will offer some kind of partnership, you’ll have to wait and see, until they announce something about that. But I am pretty sure even if so, that will likely only be for “major players”, and not just any ordinary mid-sized 3rd-party app. And even then, I doubt they would want any “hey just one click to spam the same sh*t to x dozen networks” apps.